# How can i install netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

I have installed the jdk9 but  iam not able to install the netbeans on my laptop. Once i open the setup of netbeans then it says that "jdk not found and install it". Please give me your suggestions.

My notebook configurations are:
Windows 10 
8GB RAM
HP pavilion series

Comment: Can you add the exact error message to your question? Is there a details tab you can expand that will tell you exactly where Netbeans is trying to find the JDK?

Comment: Which NetBeans version are you trying to install? NetBeans 8.2 does not work with Java 9

Comment: Iam trying to install both new and old version of the netbeans  and the error message i get every time is:
"Java SE Development Kit (JDK) was not found on this computer"      and then it gives the link for downloading jdk

Comment: And i have checked in command prompt and it shows the proper and correct message of jdk9 successfull installation.

Answer (score 0):

First check weather JDK9 is installed Properly. By checking in command prompt Using command  java -version.
And Check weather you are net beans is latest version or not.

If you want more support on JDK9 support for Net Beans , "http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDK9Support"